# Make Visual Studio work on source files developed under Mac

Tags: visual-studio, ms-office, office-js

I use `Emacs` for `Mac` to develop Excel add-ins, and test and debug them in `Excel Online` and `Chrome DevTools`. All the source files (`.xml`, `.html`, `.js`, `.css`) are put in one folder at the same level. The folder contains no more than 10 files in total, and we can add it to workspace in Chrome DevTools, which synchronises quite well with Emacs.

Once an add-in has been built more or less, I need to test (and thus debug) it further in `Excel for Windows`, which is more used by professionals and supports more complex Excel files than Excel Online. I install Windows as a virtual machine, which has access to files in Mac.

To debug an add-in in Excel for Windows, we have to use `Visual Studio`, I see how to create an add-in project from scratch in Visual Studio.

However, the question is, whether it is possible to build a project in Visual Studio, which is based on existing source files of an add-in (in one folder and at the same level). I guess only when we code and debug on the same source files across Windows (Visual Studio) and Mac (Emacs), we could keep the files synchronised.

Does anyone know what is the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for the fully interactive debug experience from Visual Studio (ie. Hit F5 and have the website, debugger and Excel all spin up at once) then this does require Visual Studio ASP.NET.

That said, you do not need to use Visual Studio to build Add-ins. All that is required is a Manifest and a Web App hosted over HTTPS. The last part is the tricky bit since you likely don't have a valid SSL Cert running on your local Mac that is also trusted on the PC. You could solve this by trusting that cert in Windows but if you're not familiar with how the Certificate Manager works it may be an exercise in frustration.

The easiest way around this is using an Azure. [Web Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/) have a [Free tier](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/) so it won't cost anything to spin it up and they include a valid SSL cert out of the box. Once you push your site up into Azure you simply need to edit the Manifest file and give it your Web App URL as the source location (i.e. https://mytestsite.azurewebsites.net/index.html).

In order to [sideload the Add-in into Excel for Windows](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins), you'll want to place the Manifest into a shared folder (SMB share). Within Excel you add that network share as a "Trusted Catalog" after which any manifest placed in that directory will show up in Excel for Windows.

Comment: Sorry, in this case which Excel will I use to debug or test my add-in? I want to make Visual Studio work because I want to test my add-in in Excel for Windows rather than Excel Online. Because Excel for Windows accepts more complex files than Excel Online, and has more functionalities...

Comment: My bad, I forgot to include a link to side loading add-ins in Windows. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I need to be able to debug my add-in with Excel for Windows. Except Visual studio, which tool (Chrome DevTools?) will allow me to do this?

Comment: That is a bit trickier. You can try creating a new project in Visual Studio and wholly replacing the default manifest with your own. That will spin up Excel and attach the debugger but I'm not sure how comprehensive it will be. I'm not able to test this scenario at the moment so please take that into account. I will test this out as soon as I can.

Comment: I've tested this using Visual Studio 2015 and an Add-in and it works marvelously. I was even able to place breakpoints in the remote JS without issues. To replicate, create a new Excel Web Add-in project in Visual Studio. Open the default manifest and paste in your manifest pointing to the Azure Web App. Hit F5 to kick off Excel and the Debugger. Once you launch the add-in you will see the JS load in the debugger.